# Python: more elegant way to assert type of function input

Tags: python, function, if-statement, types

I am a complete beginner in Python... Currently I am trying to write a function which first checks whether the inputs x and y are int or float.

My guess which does the job is

`if (type(x) != int and type(x) != float) or (type(y) != int and type(y) != float):`

However, this seems quite clumsy / inefficient to me and will be difficult to generalise in case of many inputs. Therefore I think there should be a more elegant way to write this condition..? Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: Use `isinstance()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers, isinstance() function is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`isinstance`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_isinstance.asp):

```
if not isinstance(x, (int, float)) and not isinstance(y, (int, float)):
    # do something..
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

```
if not isinstance(x, (int, float)) or not isinstance(y, (int, float)):
```

Answer (score 0):

use `isinstance` - see code example below

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/isinstance

```
def foo(x, y):
    if isinstance(x, (int, float)) and isinstance(y, (int, float)):
        print('great input')
    else:
        print('wrong input')
```

Answer (score 0):

probably the most general way is to use a base class from the [`numbers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html) module:

```
from numbers import Number

if isinstance(3.3, Number):
    ...
```

small caveat: this will also accept complex numbers (e.g. `2 + 4j`). if you want to avoid that:

```
from numbers import Real, Integral

if isinstance(3.3, (Real, Integral)):
    ...
```